# Creating new command in .sty file for LaTeX Beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a beamer theme in a .sty file, and I want to make a command `\supervisor` that works like `\author`.

In the .sty file, I added the following:

```
\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\insertsupervisor}{\supervisor}
```

But in the main file, when I declare `\supervisor{Someone}`, before `\begin{document}`, just like `\author` and `\title` etc, I get the error "Missing: begin document". The text then appears at the top of the titlepage, without the fontsize and colour that I assigned to supervisor.

How should I correctly declare this command such that it works like author for example? (I cannot find how `\author` is actually defined for beamer).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\author` works in another way: it does something like `\newcommand{\author}[1]{\def\@author{#1}}` and then you could refer to the value by calling `\@author`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to define a new command `\insertsupervisor` inside `\supervisor`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\supervisor}[1]{\gdef\insertsupervisor{#1}}

\supervisor{Foo bar}

\begin{document}

    \insertsupervisor

\end{document}
```